# How to get all the set parameters when executing a Maven plugin goal?

Tags: java, maven

```
/**
 * @goal query
 */
public class MyQueryMojo
    extends AbstractMojo
{
    /**
     * @parameter
     */
    private String param1;

    /**
     * @parameter
     */
    private String param2;

    public void execute()
        throws MojoExecutionException
    {
        showAllParams();
    }
}
```

How to implement `showAllParams()` to print the set/passed values of all the parameters when executing `mvn myquery:query -Dquery.param1=val1 -Dquery.param2=val2`?

Expected StdOut:

```
query.param1=val1
query.param2=val2
```

The intention is different from using `help:describe` because `help:describe` will return the metadata for all params while I need to get the actual passed values.

Edit: showAllParams() should not be implemented in a hardcoded fashion and it should work even with numbers of params changed.

Instead of:

```
if (param1 != null) this.getLog.info(param1);
if (param2 != null) this.getLog.info(param2);
...
if (param9 != null) this.getLog.info(param9);
```

Is it possible to do it in this fashion:

```
Map<String, String> params = getAllParams();

getLog().info(params.toString());
```

Comment: use the -debug flag?

Comment: Thanks! It works by adding debug flag. Is there any way to make it work within the Java Mojo code?

Comment: sounds like you could simply use `getLog().info( "Hello, world." );` to print out to console... do you need anything else other than that?

Comment: Sorry that I haven't made my question/requirement clear, it is surely intuitive and doable to do it in hardcoded fashion, but what if I have to add another param in the next version?

Comment: Then your next version would need to add another logging statement.  I am not sure I understand your question then. Can you clarify your requirements?

Comment: Thank you ochi, I have updated my question and please check if I make my question clear.

Comment: Since it is confirmed that the maven basic configurator can list all these params using --debug, I am wondering if I can call it in code as well, something like getConfigurator().getParameters()

Comment: A few remaining questions related to your use case?  The way I understand it, you would like to print the parameters passed in to your plugin (via command line) - you are expecting certain parameters and want to know if they are being set (or not) and log/display it.  1) Why is `--debug` not enough for your needs 2) why would you want to print an unknown number of parameters? 3) If your plugin does not use a parameter, why do you want to print it? 4) if you plugin does use a parameter, then you already should have a name for it, and the named param solution should  be enough, right?

Comment: If you run `mvn -X plugin:goal` all the parameters with the values will be printed out...why would like to print them out ? The documentation of the plugin will give the user the information he/she needs? And yes I agree with ochi...A parameter of a plugin has an intention which means if it is usefull for the user I would print out a message about it..but not all parameters...Furthermore if you have too much parameters that sounds you don't separate the concerns of your goals...one goal one concern...the less parameter...

Answer (score 1):

Well, considering that param1 and param2 are not initialized and have no default value, you could just check all of the parameters, and if a parameter isn't null, then you print it. In your case:

```
if (param1 != null) this.getLog.info(param1);
if (param2 != null) this.getLog.info(param2);
```

However, if you have a parameter with a default value, then according to the following link (http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Check-if-parameter-is-explicitly-set-td5905937.html), there is no way of telling whether a value is explicitly set by the command line or is set as a default value.

Comment: Sorry that I haven't made my question/requirement clear, it is surely intuitive  and doable to do it in hardcoded fashion, but what if I have to add another param in the next version?

Comment: Thanks for sharing, legs. The link shared by you is also really helpful for what I am working on. Can you check my updated question description and see if there is any solution?

Comment: For that, I think you would have to check all fields of the class, and see which ones have javadocs that equal "@parameter". I'm not entirely sure about that, though. I'm trying to figure out what will work.

Comment: Thank you, legs. Btw, https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-plugin-api/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/descriptor/MojoDescriptor.html#getParameterMap() seems related to our discussion.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use MojoDescriptor for this purpose, but if you assume that all your fields are maven parameters, then you could use this.getClass.getDeclaredFields() to get all the fields. Sorry if I wasn't helpful enough.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my take on it.

Notice that you can pass named parameters (i.e. "`-Dquery.param1=1`") or an array of parameter values.

Array type parameters are configured by specifying the parameter multiple times.

(i.e. "`-Dquery.param1=1 -Dquery.param1=11`" ,  etc.)

More information on the docs:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

```
/**
 * @goal query
 */
public class MyQueryMojo extends AbstractMojo{

    private final static String PARAM1_DEFAULT_VALUE="param1";
    private final static String PARAM2_DEFAULT_VALUE="param2";
    private final static String PARAM3_DEFAULT_VALUE="param3";

    /**
     *  param1
     */
    @Parameter( property = "query.param1", defaultValue = PARAM1_DEFAULT_VALUE )
    private String param1;

    /**
     *  param1
     */
    @Parameter( property = "query.param2", defaultValue = PARAM2_DEFAULT_VALUE )
    private String param2;

    /**
     *  param1
     */
    @Parameter( property = "query.param3", defaultValue = PARAM3_DEFAULT_VALUE )
    private String param3;

    /**
     *  paramArray
     */
    @Parameter( property = "query.param")
    private String[] paramArray;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException{
        // print individual parameters
        printAllParams();

        // print all in array
        printArrayParam();
    }

    private void printArrayParam(){
        for(String p : paramArray){
            getLog.info( "paramArray: " + p );
        }
    }

    private void printAllParams(){
        getLog().info("param1:" + param1);
        getLog().info("param2:" + param2);
        getLog().info("param3:" + param3);
    }
}
```